# Is L-Smoothness Equivalent to Globally Lipschitz Gradient without Convexity

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions, gradient-descent

#### **The problem I am Having**

Suppose $f:\mathbb E\mapsto \mathbb{\bar R}$, mapping from some euclidean space to augmented real with a well-defined gradient defined everywhere, and it has the smooth property:

$$
\exists L > 0 \text{ s.t: }
|f(y) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), y - x\rangle| \le \frac{L}{2}\Vert x - y\Vert^2 
\quad \forall x, y\in \mathbb E, 
$$

then, is it possible that the function's gradient is globally Lipschitz? For generality, we may assume $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is any norm, but proving it only for Euclidean norm suffices the argument.

For context, I am just curious because the converse of the statement is a simple proof, but this statement is not; I assume smoothness and then get a globally Lipschitz gradient without convexity assumption, and it makes me feel unease.

---

#### **What I had Tried**

A list of things I tried to solve it.

- Simple algebraic manipulations, thinking that taking supremum or Cauchy Schwartz inequality might help.
- Googling and some UCLA lecture slides are what I found to be the closest: [here](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/236C/lectures/gradient.pdf#page14); however, they assume the convexity of the function to prove the statement.
- Looking for counter-examples, where some non-convex/non-concave function might be smoothly bounded above and below two quadratics and have non- globally Lipschitz gradient but failed.

Some help and pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I found a counter-example; it's $x^2\sin(x^{-1})$, it's smooth, but its gradient is not Lipchitz; as theory predicted, it's non-convex.

Comment: That idea was wrong, and at the current stage, I still haven't solved this mystery yet.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\pm f(x) + L\Vert x\Vert_2^2/2$ is convex and smooth, then we can apply existing conditions for smooth and convex functions. Let $\varphi = f + L/2 \Vert \cdot\Vert_2^2$, the following is equivalent

$$
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{1}{2L}\Vert \nabla \varphi (y) - \nabla \varphi (x)\Vert_2^2 
    & \le 
    \langle \nabla \varphi(y) - \nabla \varphi(x), y - x\rangle
    \\
    \Vert \nabla \varphi (y) - \nabla \varphi (x)\Vert_2^2  
    &\le 
    2L\langle \nabla \varphi(y) - \nabla\varphi(x), y -x\rangle, 
\end{aligned}
$$

Starting with the LHS of the inequality then

$$
\begin{aligned}
    &\; \Vert \nabla \varphi(y) - \nabla \varphi(x)\Vert_2^2
    \\
    &= 
    \Vert L(y - x) + (\nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x))\Vert_2^2
    \\
    &= 
    L^2\Vert y -x \Vert_2^2 + 
    \Vert \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)\Vert_2^2
    + 
    2L\left\langle 
        y - x, \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)
    \right\rangle, 
\end{aligned}
$$
The RHS of the inequality is given as
$$
\begin{aligned}
    &\; 2L\langle \nabla \varphi(y) - \nabla\varphi(x), y -x\rangle
    \\
    &= 
    2L \langle L(y - x) + \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x), y - x\rangle 
    \\
    &= 2L^2\Vert y - x\Vert_2^2 + 2L \langle \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x), y -x\rangle, 
\end{aligned}
$$

the cross term $2L\langle y - x, \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x) \rangle$ cancels out at bothside then we have the inequality

$$
\begin{aligned}
    L^2 \Vert y - x\Vert_2^2 + \Vert \nabla f(y) - \nabla f(x)\Vert_2^2
    &\le 2L^2\Vert y - x\Vert_2^2, 
\end{aligned}
$$

subtracting $L^2\Vert y- x\Vert^2_2$at both side will yield the Lipschitz continuity results of the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered very similar and related question. That is whether the following conditions are equivalent to each other,

(1) $f$ is $L$-smooth ($\|f(x) - f(y)\| \leq L \| x-y \|$)

(2) $|D_f(x,y)| \leq \frac{L}{2}\|x-y\|^2$

(3) $\|\nabla^2 f\| \leq L$.

Without otherwise stated, we consider Euclidean norm for both vectors and matrices. Here we define the Bregman distance $D_f(x,y) = f(x) - f(y) - \langle \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle$.

(1) $\iff$ (3) can be found in Lemma 1.2.2 in (Nesterov et.al 2018)

(1) $\implies$ (2) can be found in Lemma 1.2.3 in (Nesterov et.al 2018)

Then I find [smooth convex generalizations](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Esidford/courses/19fa_opt_theory/sidford_mse213_2019fa_chap_5_smooth_convex_gen.pdf)'s Lemma 8 shows that $|D_f (x,y)| \leq \frac{L}{2}\|x-y\|^2 \iff |z^\mathsf{T} \nabla^2 f(x) z| \leq L \|z\|^2$ ($z$ can be any vector), which means (2) $\iff$ (3).

So now, I wonder whether it holds that (1) $\iff$ (2) $\iff$ (3)?

At last, I think this question is asking whether (1) $\iff$ (2)?

Nesterov, Y. (2018). Lectures on convex optimization (Vol. 137, pp. 5-9). Berlin: Springer.